# How to render to an OpenGL texture with ExoPlayer and display it in Unity3D?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, exoplayer

I want to use ExoPlayer to progressively stream videos from urls, but display the video in Unity3D.
I first tested it with a surfaceview in a native android app and it works brilliantly.
However, I need this functionality to be contained into an aar library and use it as a plugin for Unity.
I am VERY close to make it work (or so it seems), but I know my lack of OpenGL knowledge is not letting me advance.
Should the texture be created in Unity-side or in the plugin-side?
When should it be re-created and how?
When should it be destroyed and how?

I tried several combinations and only a black texture is shown. Audio works in each case.
The code is a mess, as now I'm still in the "discovering" stage and I'm trying everything I can think of.
I didn't delete all the comments in the code, so you can see what other approaches I used. I also put some questions in the comments.
I know the solution needs unity+exoplayer+opengl+android knowledge at the same time, so [I also posted this on Unity Android forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/proper-way-of-updating-a-texture-outside-unity.439733/) and linked the posts to each other. Hopefully, I can combine the answers I get here with those ones and come up with the solution.

**Android side:**

```
public class ExoPlayerForUnity {
    static SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
    static Surface surface;

    static Context getUnityContext() {
        try {
            Class<?> unityPlayerClass = Class.forName("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            Field currentActivity = unityPlayerClass.getField("currentActivity");
            Object o = currentActivity.get(null);
            return (Context)o;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    public static int init( String uriString) {

        Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(uriString);

        final Activity unityContext = (Activity)getUnityContext();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
//        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
//        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
//        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new FixedTrackSelection.Factory();
//        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(mainHandler, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(handler, null);
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        final SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(unityContext, trackSelector, loadControl, null, false);

        DefaultBandwidthMeter defBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(unityContext,
                Util.getUserAgent(unityContext, "yourApplicationName"), defBandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI,
                dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, new Handler(), new ExtractorMediaSource.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadError(IOException error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        // Maybe useful?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324753/how-to-use-unity-createexternaltexture-on-android
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        final int texture = textures[0];

//        //GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
//        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
//        //GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, 1024, 512, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
//        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
//        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
//        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
//        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
//        GLES20.glBindTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
        GLES20.glTexParameteri( GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
        GLES20.glBindTexture( GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0 );



        // TODO work with attachToGLContext maybe?
        surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texture);

        surfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(final SurfaceTexture sf) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Should I use this or update it in Unity-side with tex.UpdateTextureExternal(tex.GetNativeTexturePtr()) ?
                        //GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture);
                        //sf.updateTexImage();
                        //GLES20.glBindTexture( GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0 );
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.v("ExoPlayerForUnity", "buff: " + player.getBufferedPercentage());
                    }
                }, 3000, 1000
        );

        player.setVideoSurface(surface);
        player.prepare(videoSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        return texture;
    }
}
```

**Unity side:**

```
public class ExoTestPlugin : MonoBehaviour
{
    new Renderer renderer;
    Texture2D rt;
    //RenderTexture rt; // maybe this?
    AndroidJavaClass jc;
    int texName;
    float curScale = 0f;

    void init()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Camera.onPreRender += OnPreRender2;

        jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.thefallengames.exoplayerforunity.ExoPlayerForUnity");

        texName = jc.CallStatic<int>("init", 0, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");


        //rt = new Texture2D(640, 360, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true, true);
        //rt = new Texture2D(640, 360, TextureFormat.ETC2_RGBA8, true, true);
        //rt = new RenderTexture(640, 360, 24, RenderTextureFormat.Default, RenderTextureReadWrite.Default);
        //rt.Create();

        rt = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(1024, 512, TextureFormat.ETC_RGB4, true, true, (IntPtr)texName);

        renderer.material.mainTexture = rt;
    }

    void Update () {

        // Here I'm just starting the playback on first tap and then toggling between 2x and 1x scale on any subsequent taps
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (curScale == 0f)
            {
                curScale = 1f;
                init();

                return;
            }

            if (curScale == 2f)
                curScale = .5f;
            else
                curScale = 2f;
            transform.localScale *= curScale;
        }
    }

    void OnPreRender2(Camera cam)
    {
        if (jc == null) // not inited
            return;

        if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 60) != 0) // updating ~once per second only, just for debugging
            return;

        rt.UpdateExternalTexture((IntPtr)texName);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Also checked [this post](https://medium.com/@cinemur/exoplayer-for-building-powerful-vr-players-for-cardboard-and-gearvr-73ec7e83dd5c#.4ik6oq1kd), but it just says it's possible, it doesn't give any useful details.
Note that I also tried to create the texture in unity and pass the pointer to the java-side and that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: But `init()` is never called.... Aren't you suppose to call that from the `Start` function function?

Comment: Hi! Look for this comment "// Here I'm just starting the playback on first tap and then toggling between 2x and 1x scale on any subsequent taps"

Comment: Ok, I see that.

Comment: No one?..... :(

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'd like to render from ExoPlayer to a native OpenGLES texture too

Comment: Nope. I dropped it

Comment: I have the same issue with you [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323258/how-can-i-render-the-byte-array-fast-which-get-from-android-in-unity3d?noredirect=1#comment93537763_53323258) Did you solve it?