# How Can I render the byte array fast which get from Android in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working an Project that requires render the byte array data from Android in Unity3D.

that is what I do:

```
stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start(); 
texture.LoadImage(RowData); // RowData is the data which get form Android
texture.Apply();
stopwatch.Stop(); 
TimeSpan timespan = stopwatch.Elapsed; 
double milliseconds = timespan.TotalMilliseconds;
```

milliseconds  is average 200+ ms.
How can I Optimize the texture loading process?

Comment: How big is the file?  What type interface are you using (ethernet, serial port, USB).  What is the data rate?

Comment: You can start by removing `texture.apply()` per the documentation of LoadImage, it is unnecessary.  https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html

Comment: the byte stream is download by Android Lib which is compiled to the  xxx.jar for unity. the resolution of the video is 3840x1920.

Comment: removing  `texture.apply()` does not minus the cost time. it is still 200+ms.